# Is there an official streamlined/simplified version of the D20 system?

Tags: game-design, d20-system, ogl, d20-modern

I'm considering building my own RPG, the setting is already underway I just need a system. For sake of expediency, recognizability and legality I'd like to use an existing system as the base.

The only open game license that I know of is for the D20 System, and it's the rule set that I "get" the best.

The D20 System is "crunchy", mechanically speaking it has a lot of moving parts. For ease of building and eventual play, I'd want a version of D20 that had as few moving parts as possible without it becoming a rule-lite and or Narrativist game like Fate or Powered By the Apocalypse.

So I'm asking did Wizard of the Coast ever release a streamlined/simplified version of the D20 system, and if the answer is yes was this system released under the OGL?

Comment: Sorry, there are a lot of streamlined d20 variants, and unfortunately answering this **usefully** is basically giving recommendations on which suit your requirements. It's been determined through trial and error that recommendation requests don't work well here due to the site just being not suited to them. For these cases we suggest asking [on an RPG forum *(list of options)*](http://meta.rpg.stackexchange.com/q/5449), where more informal back-and-forth discussions can be had with knowledgeable folks until you can settle on a game/engine that fits your preferences and needs.

Comment: I don't need a discussion, just answer to the question of did Wotc publish a simplified version of D20 under the OGL.

Comment: They did not. But that's not what our helpful members would answer with — they would say no, and then start compiling all kinds of “but this 3rd party variant…” material, of which there is a *lot*. Which is off topic, so questions that must have those kinds of answers are put on hold as off topic. Sorry! Questions that are looking for a system to use are just off topic here.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie you've just answered my question. With three words.

Comment: Incompletely though, because the question misunderstands the OGL and "officianess", and a full answer would correct the misunderstanding. This is basically a request for a d20 variant that is streamlined and "official", and would get many recommendations which discarded the misplaced emphasis on "official". But recommendation-seeking questions are off topic. Even asking for "streamlined official d20 OGL system" is off topic, even if there is only one, because asking for a system that marches certain requirements is off topic here.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie No you gave the exact answer that I was looking for. I now know that there is no official streamlined version of D20.

Comment: Please take further concerns or discussion to [meta]. /cc @Daniel

Comment: For reference, here's [a meta discussion](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6894/23970) of this question's topicality/closure.